# Highlight current page with one sitemap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a sitemap.php which is "`<?php include 'sitemap.php'; ?>`" included on every page. Before I made this, I had this sitemap on every single HTML or PHP site.

So now: I want to keep this single php file but, if the user clicks on a link, this site he'll be redirected to should be highlighted now. Short: Highlight the current page but with one sitemap-file.

My CSS for highlighting:

```
li.active {
  color: #fff;
}
```

and I guess you all know how a sitemap looks:

```
               <ul class="nav nav-menu">
                  <li><a href="channel.php">
                      <div class="nav-menu__ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment"></i></div>
                      <div class="nav-menu__text"><span>Channel</span></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="products.html">
                      <div class="nav-menu__ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i></div>
                      <div class="nav-menu__text"><span>Groups</span></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="groups.php">
                      <div class="nav-menu__ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i></div>
                      <div class="nav-menu__text"><span>Ranking</span></div></a></li>
                  <li><a href="users.html">
                      <div class="nav-menu__ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></div>
                      <div class="nav-menu__text"><span>Users</span></div></a></li>
                </ul>
```

I guess it have to be done with JS / jQuery / PHP, but I really don't know how.

Comment: Simple enough on server since you know which page is being rendered. Or parse url in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url page without heading or trailing part and as soon as the page is ready. Than you can mark your li closest element with the new class:

```js
$(function () {
  var pageUrl = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop();
  $('a[href="' + pageUrl + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li.active {
  color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-menu">
    <li><a href="channel.php">
        <div class="nav-menu__ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment"></i></div>
        <div class="nav-menu__text"><span>Channel</span></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">
        <div class="nav-menu__ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-users"></i></div>
        <div class="nav-menu__text"><span>Groups</span></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="groups.php">
        <div class="nav-menu__ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i></div>
        <div class="nav-menu__text"><span>Ranking</span></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="users.html">
        <div class="nav-menu__ico"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></div>
        <div class="nav-menu__text"><span>Users</span></div></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, i thank you for your help :D! +1